# Exception connecting Azure Sql Server and Spring Boot

Tags: sql-server, spring, maven, azure, spring-boot

I'm trying configure a app in Spring Boot to connect with Azure DataBase using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver driver.

This is my configuration:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://hdonrns815.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=code_dev
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

this is my SQL Server pom.xml configuration:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this is the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:d7304f30-4c29-4258-ac9f-4409dee20fdd
```

I can connect to the DB from Sql Server management.

I don't know what happend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Allow Azure Services to access Azure SQL.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#connecting-from-azure

Comment: I can connect to the DB from Sql Server management because this is configurate.

Comment: SSMS isn't Azure service, you need to enable Azure Services specifically

Comment: Are you running your spring boot application from the same machine as that you have SSMS (for which IP is already whitelisted) or have you deployed/running from some other machine.

Comment: Same machine and I can connect to the DB, but not in Spring Boot